# Подключение к серверу postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Установил сервер postgres 11. При подключении сбросил старый пароль и создал новый.  При вводе нового пароля окно ввода скрывается и открывается снова без всякой информации. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Что за окно? Есть ли логи клиента или сервера?

Comment: Окно ввода пароля при подключении к серверу. Не знаю как фото прикрепить.как посмотреть логи?

Comment: В linux логи постгреса будут в /var/log/postgresql скорее всего, в windows - посмотрите в eventlog или в каталоге pg_log внутри каталога PGDATA